# Read EDI X12 File and convert Using Talend Open Studio

Tags: talend, edi, x12

I am new to EDI. I got some information about EDI from [Here](http://www.xtranslator.com/prod/beginguidex12.pdf). I heard that [Talend](http://www.talend.com/) supports reading of EDI X12 files using some technique called **Smooks**. I downloaded 
**Talend Open Studio for Data Integration v5.3.1**. But I don't know how to Use it for reading EDI file

I got a EDI text from one site

```
ISA*00* *00* *12*3109992367T *ZZ*IAISNOKIST *070103*0839*^*00307*000024398*0*P*>~
GS*OG*3109992367*IAISNOKIST*20070103*0839*24398*T*004010UCS~
ST*875*000024479~
G50*N*20071230*59590001~
G62*10*20070106~
NTE*GEN*59590001~
NTE*GEN*IF ANY CHANGES OR SHORTAGES PLEASE~
NTE*GEN*CONTACT ALLY SMITH (310) 256-9388~
NTE*GEN*OR EMAIL ASMITH@AOL.COM~
G66*CC*H~
N1*BT*UNIFIED WESTERN GROCERS*9*0063333040005~
N3*PO BOX 11111 TERMINAL WAY~
N4*LOS ANGELES CA 900250000~
N1*ST*CGC MECHANIZED WAREHOUSE*9*0069333040180~
N3*1200 SHEILA AV~
N4*COMMERCE CA 900400000~
N1*BO*MY COMPANY NAME*9*193807245~
G68*10*CA*1.57*006121100201~
G69*SPRINGFIELD APPLESAUCE~
G70*1*5*OZ~
G68*10*CA*3.98*006121100202~
G69*SPRINGFIELD FANCY APPLESAUCE~
G70*1*5*OZ~
G76*100*CA~
SE*23*000024479~
GE*1*24398~
IEA*1*000024398~
```

I want to save this as a EDI file. What should be its extension? And is there any link for steps or demo for using Talend to read this file and parse it to some readable file like **CSV or XML**?

Thanks

Comment: Did you ever find a viable solution for this issue? I am in the process of parsing and creating EDI X12 documents with Talend and am at a loss. Any information would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: With Talend You cannot do. But you have to look at the latest version of TOS, may be they support it. Check for edireader. It's opensource, It will create XML file. May be useful for you. Only few are open source as I know, which couldn't help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not many people seems to remark this, but `Talend Open Studio for Data` come with a default project called **Demo project** (see picture below).

[image: Talend demo project]

This project contains tons of examples of how to use Talend. You should find everything there. Every job is very well documented, example :

[image: Documented job example]

Official online documentation can be found here : http://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/menu.php (free registration may be required at some point)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But can you please tell me where can I find the demo for reading EDI file? Because I could not find any demo inside that **TALENDDEMOSJAVA **

Comment: Your use case seems a little bit specific. You can however, adapt an existing demo job to your needs. Maybe you could edit your question, and state what have you tried so far.