# Read file from dynamic file location using talend

Tags: java, file-upload, sh, talend

I am using Talend Studio for Data Integration v5.3.1.

In that I created a **Job** for **fileDelimited**. I have uploaded a CSV file and it is reading the file.

I exported the Job as a Zip file, extracted it, and I run the **sh** file in Terminal. And it was reading the file and displaying it in the console.

Now I want to read a different file in some other file location. is it possible to read the different file by running the same shell script? If so, where I have to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it using context variables, and context load. 
create configuration file which will have all the required input location path and other details.

you have different files on different location and you just wanted upload files without file parsing  right? if so then

first create configuration file with two parameters.

```
FilePath|FileName
\\Folderone\|File1.txt
\\Foldertwo\|File2.txt
```

create two context variables in context named as FilePath & FileName
and then used tContextLoad to load above configuration details to context variable

used these variables to provide file and path at runtime from configuration.

Comment: Thanks. how can I do it? I am new to this. is there any demo or something?

Comment: right now i don`t have any demo ready but i can create, if specify your requirement in detail

Comment: Thanks. I want to upload a different file with different delimiter(specify file location in sh file) so it should read the file

Comment: you have different files on different location and just wanted upload no file parsing  right? if so then create job like below

Comment: of course file parsing too. I want all the features of Talend for file delimited. But only thing is I should be able to specify different file . The Java program generated by Talend has the file location hard coded, the time I upload the file. That I want to make dynamic. And also in the `toString()` all the headers of file was hard coded.

Comment: then you have to do so much stuff, if your files has different  schema then you have to use Dynamic Schema. by using configuration file or table you can make the job parametrised.

Comment: Is it possible to create dynamic schema on free version of talend? I am using Free version

Comment: OK!. Thanks. I was trying this for while

Answer (score 0):

See my answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17565718/921244 to have guidance on how to open the Demo project.

There you will find a demo job for loading `Context variables`.

If you want an online example, take a look at the official documentation : http://www.talendforge.org/tutorials/tutorial.php?language=english&idTuto=34